# Prove that $\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac {\sin^2\theta (cos\theta - a)}{(1-a \,cos \theta)^4}}d \theta = 0$ for $0<=a<1$

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to prove that for $0<=a<1$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac {\sin^2\theta (cos\theta - a)}{(1-a \,cos \theta)^4}}d \theta = 0$$

I know that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac {\sin\theta \,cos\theta}{(1-a \,cos \theta)^4}}d \theta = 0$$

and $$\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac {3a\sin\theta}{(1-a \,cos \theta)^4}}d \theta = 
\int_0^{2\pi}{\frac {cos\theta}{(1-a \,cos \theta)^3}}d \theta$$

I have tried substituting this last equation into the first but it doesn't seem to produce any obvious simplifications.

Comment: What are the allowed values of $a$?

Comment: @amcalde. Yes sorry I forgot to add, initially. Question has been updated now. Thanks for reminder.

Comment: Hmm. Seems hard. By the way, $a=0$ is easy to show. So you may as well put $0 \le a < 1$.

Comment: @amcalde.Thanks for the pointer re a=0. Have added info on indefinite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indefinite integral has an elementary closed form.  Let $$f_a(\theta) = \frac{\sin^2 \theta (\cos \theta - a)}{(1 - a \cos \theta)^4},$$ and $$u = \frac{1 - a \cos \theta}{\sin \theta}, \quad du = \frac{a - \cos\theta}{\sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta,$$ and thus $$\int f_a(\theta) \, d\theta = -\int u^{-4} \, du = \frac{1}{3} u^{-3} + C = \frac{\sin^3 \theta}{3(1-a \cos\theta)^3} + C.$$  Evaluating this for $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$ shows that the definite integral is zero.

Comment: Thanks that looks nice and simple.  I wonder why WolframAlpha (see the end of my question) gives a different indefinite integral formula from yours?

Comment: Aha, my error. My expansion (and thus my indefinite integral therefrom) were wrong.

Comment: I think your result should have cos in the denominator instead of sin.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a neat complex analysis trick to integrals of the form
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} F(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)\ \mathrm{d}\theta. $$
Make the substitution $z = e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. This transforms the contour of integration from the interval $[0,2\pi]$ into the unit circle $C_1(0)$ lying in the complex plane. We can obtain $\mathrm{d}\theta$ as
$$ \mathrm{d}z = i e^{i\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta \implies \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}. $$
Furthermore, observe that $\frac{1}{z} = e^{-i\theta} = \cos \theta - i \sin \theta$, so we can obtain $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ as 
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \left( z + \frac{1}{z} \right) \hspace{1cm} \sin \theta = \frac{1}{2i} \left( z - \frac{1}{z} \right). $$
For your integral, this substitution produces
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta (\cos \theta - a)}{(1 - a \cos \theta)^4} \mathrm{d}\theta = \int_{C_1(0)} \frac{2 i \left(z^2-1\right)^2 \left(z^2 - 2az +1\right)}{\left(a z^2 - 2z +a\right)^4} \mathrm{d}z.$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: .Thanks, I will try...but it make take me some time as I am not familiar with complex integrals.

Comment: @steveOw The next step is to apply the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). We want to find the poles of that rational function which lie within the unit circle. There is only one such pole, of order 4, given by $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$.

Comment: I looked at the Residue Theorem but it is too advanced for me personally to tackle at present.